# How to execute URL command in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am fairly new in R programming and I wanted to know if anyone knows a way to make R execute a URL.

I will explain my problem:

In the website that I'm trying to get data from you get data only for one city and one year, and of course I need all the years and many cities.
Every time the user get the data in Excel format and is directed to the site: https://www.police.gov.il/MapSkifoutService?city=8300&street=&house=&subjects=1,2,10,11&quarter=1,2,3,4&year=2017&mode=excel.
Sadly, using read.url is not helping, because there is not excel or csv yet, only after executing the URL - the user get the Excel.
I wish to create a loop that will take all the data from all the years and all the cities, but how do I make R execute the URL command so I will have all the data available?

Comment: see if r package `rvest` helps you

Comment: almost! i used it html_session to get the session but i dont know to turn it back to an excel or a dataframe

Comment: You'll need to use the `splashr` or `seleniumPipes` packages. The site does a javascript test before serving up the content.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the raw bytes as an xlsx seems to work:

```
resp <- POST("https://www.police.gov.il/MapSkifoutService",
    body=list(city=8300,
        street="",
        house="",
        subjects="1,2,10,11",
        quarter="1,2,3,4",
        year=2017,
        mode="excel"))
writeBin(resp$content, "test.xlsx")
```